# External monitor option for MacBook AIr

Tags: macbook-pro

I understand it is possilble to connect an external monitor to my MacBook Air. For photo editing can I have both screens open at the same time ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both the external display and the internal display will be active at the same time, unless you close your MacBook.

Have a look at Apple support article [HT5019: How to use multiple displays with your Mac](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5019) for more details if you need them.